# How to set specific Meta Tag values while creating Article Content.?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I am using Meta tags(Module: [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)) on my Article content type page. I want to set specific  Meta Tag values depending on Article type I select for example by default check some check box for robots.

Does this possible in Drupal 7. If yes please give sample code for doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any code for that, that [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module has that functionality built into it

These 2 listed features could apply to your use case specifically:

> - Per entity and per entity bundle to control default meta tags for all items of a certain type, e.g. all nodes of a certain content type.
> - Ability to override meta tags on each entity object, e.g. to override meta tags on an individual node.